# HTML: Linkar uma mudança de pagina

Tags: html

Eu estou fazendo um trabalho para faculdade no qual eu tenho que fazer um site em HTML como se fosse de uma empresa.

Na coluna da direita eu prentendo colocar links que carregariam outras paginas na area vazia mas sem recarregar a pagina inteira

Toda ajuda é apreciada[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode usar iframes aprenda a fazer neste link
https://www.codigofonte.net/dicas/html/296_direcionar-links-para-um-iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais simples é utilizar **[iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)**, mas você pode utilizar jQuery, XMLHttpRequest, etc.

### Exemplo com iframe

```js
var menu = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a");
var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");

menu.forEach(function(el) {
   el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      alert("Nesse site não vai funcionar");
      iframe.src = el.getAttribute("href");
   });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 100%
}
nav ul li {
  float:left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background:#CCC;
}

iframe {
  float:left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://www.google.com.br">Google</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://fb.com">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com">Twitter</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <iframe src="/"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado.